# Cosmology, transpose of partial derivatives and Riemannian metrics

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, matrix-elements

In general relativity and cosmology, Riemannian metrics play an important role. Here, I have a few related questions about the algebraic manipulation of derivatives and Riemannian metrics in the framework outlined above. As a result, I decided to keep my doubts in this single post rather than different questions on the same topic. **In addition, it should be noted that I have read previous questions and posts on Physics.StackExchange on this subject, however, did not help.**

With that said, suppose that we have the following Riemannian metric tensor,

$$G_{\alpha\, \alpha}=2\sum_{i=1}^{2}\left(\frac{\partial \psi_{i}}{\partial X^{\alpha}}\right)^{2}$$.

Based on the above:

1. Is it true that $G_{\alpha\, \alpha}=A^{\text{T}}A$, in which $A$  is the Jacobian matrix?

**My attempts**:

It is not difficult to realize that $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\partial \psi_{i}}{\partial X^{\alpha}}\right)$ is the proper definition of the Jacobian matrix. That is to say,$A=\displaystyle\left(\frac{\partial \psi_{i}}{\partial X^{\alpha}}\right)$.

However, how may I perform the transpose operation of a derivative and determine whether or not $G_{\alpha \, \alpha}=A^{\text{T}}A$ is  true?

2. May we conclude that $\sqrt{G_{\alpha \, \alpha}}$ is the same as the determinant of $A$?
3. Are there other ways to rewrite $G_{\alpha \, \alpha}$ in terms of $A$ through matrix operations?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands you first equation does not make sense as you have a sum on $\alpha$ on the RHS but still have $\alpha$'s on the LHS.

Also I think hyou are confusing the Jacobian *matrix* with the jacobian *determinant*.

I think that you mean something like
$$
g_{\mu\nu}= \sum_{a=1}^N \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial \xi^\mu} \frac{\partial x^a}{\partial \xi^\nu}
$$

which is the metric  for curvilinear coordinates $\xi^\mu$, $\mu,\nu = 1,\ldots, M$  on an $M$ dimensional surface embedded in an $N$ dimensional  euclidean space with cartesian coordinates $x^a$.

Comment: Hi, @Mike stone. I hope you are doing well. Thanks for commenting. The metric elements of the first equation do not have off-diagonal components. That is to say, my first equation only has $g_{11}$ and $g_{22}$. Second, here I understand $A$ as the Jacobian matrix. I have edited the post considering your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back from the explicit example you stated and let's consider a general metric $g_{\alpha \beta} (x)$. If one performs a general coordinate transformation, the new metric shall be:

\begin{equation}
g '_{\mu \nu} = g_{\alpha \beta} \, \frac{\partial x^{\alpha }}{\partial x' ^{\mu}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta }}{\partial x' ^{\nu}}
\end{equation}

Assuming that the transformation is invertible, there exists a corresponding Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{J}$ for the transformation which shall contain the elements $\frac{\partial x' ^{\mu }}{\partial x ^{\alpha}}$. Therefore we claim we can rewrite the expression above in matrix form as:

\begin{equation}
g' = \mathbf{\bar{J}}^{\text{T}} \, g \,  \mathbf{\bar{J}}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{\bar{J}}$ the Jacobian matrix for the inverse transformation. Here I shall address your question with regards to how to verify how one may correctly deduce that we take a transpose matrix. To do that, we may write the Jacobian matrix with indices as $\bar{J}^{\alpha }{}_{\mu } = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha }}{\partial x' ^{\mu}}$ and thus the transposition in this notation is simply a change of index ordering:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\bar{J}} \rightarrow \bar{J}^{\alpha }{}_{\mu } \Rightarrow \,  (\mathbf{\bar{J}})^{\text{T}} \rightarrow \bar{J}_{\mu }{}^{\alpha }
\end{equation}

To correctly reproduce the matrix form above, the corresponding quantities with indices should be ordered in such a way as to have the same indices adjacent:

\begin{equation}
g '_{\mu \nu} = \bar{J}_{\mu }{}^{\alpha } \, g_{\alpha \beta} \, \bar{J}^{\beta }{}_{\nu }
\end{equation}

which as you can see leads to the matrix form of the transformation we predicted.

Continuing, the volume element shall then be:

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{|\det{g'}|} = \det{\mathbf{\bar{J}}} \, \sqrt{|\det{g}|}
\end{equation}

Since $\det{\mathbf{\bar{J}}} = (\det{\mathbf{J}})^{-1}$ and the Jacobian determinant $\det{\mathbf{J}}$ appears in the integrals after the general coordinate transformation, the last equation ensures that the volume of the manifold remains invariant, as it should:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\int _{\mathcal{V}} d^{d}x \, \sqrt{|\det{g}|} \rightarrow \\
\int _{\mathcal{V}} d^{d}x' \, \sqrt{|\det{g'}|} = \int _{\mathcal{V}} d^{d}x \, \det{\mathbf{J}} \,  &\sqrt{|\det{g'}|} = \int _{\mathcal{V}} d^{d}x \, \det{\mathbf{J}}\det{\mathbf{\bar{J}}} \,  \sqrt{|\det{g}|} = \int _{\mathcal{V}} d^{d}x \, \sqrt{|\det{g}|}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, back to your example: consider a 2-dimensional metric that is given by the Jacobian matrix multiplication $A^{\text{T}} A$, where the Jacobian elements are given by $\frac{\partial \psi ^{i}}{\partial X^{\alpha}}$. What you are implicitly stating is that the new metric $G$ is simply the result of a general coordinate transformation of the 2-dimensional Euclidean metric:

\begin{equation}
\delta _{ij} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where the old manifold coordinates are $\psi ^{i}$, while the new ones (for the metric $G_{\alpha \beta}$) are $X^{\alpha}$. By our analysis above, the answer to your second question becomes rather obvious: the volume element of a Euclidean metric is 1, therefore indeed the volume element in the new coordinates is $\sqrt{\det{G}} = \det{A}$.

As for the third question, I don't see how you can rewrite it otherwise in terms of $A$, at least in a manner that's useful and/or non-trivial. Perhaps you'd like to elaborate on what kind of alternative relation you might expect so we can narrow it down a bit.